# i can't showing value request.getParameter()

Tags: jsp

in url = http://localhost:/test/buku.jsp?act=add

```
<%
  if(request.getParameter("act") == "add"){
    out.println(request.getParameter("act"));
  }
%>
```

[i can't showing value request.getParameter()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlVNR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare string values in java:

```
request.getParameter("act").equals("add")
```